# Swift DateFormatter - print week of year and year

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to print a given date in the format of "[week in a year] [year]" combination using a `DateFormatter`. I have given it a pattern of "w yyyy" but it returns an empty string.

```
let date = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2018, month: 9, day: 28).date
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("w yyyy")
formatter.string(from: date!) // this returns ""

formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("w")
formatter.string(from: date!) // this returns the correct number, like "36"
```

According to the [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1), iOS 5 uses [version tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns). I assume that it hasn't changed since then.

In the unicode.org documentation, there is no special mention of how week of year is behaving in conjunction with a year format. What am I missing here?

**EDIT** I understand that I can use `DateComponents` to get the numbers and formatting them that way, but this question is more about why the format `"w yyyy"` is special.

Comment: You are using the wrong format. For `weekOfYear` you should use `Y` instead of `yyyy`

Comment: @LeoDabus you mean `"w YYYY"` or `"w Y"`?

Comment: you just need a single Y `"w Y"`. YYYY probably would behave the same way

Comment: Using `"w Y"` with `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` also just returns an empty string, but it is the more correct format to use. The only way I can get it to work is to assign it directly to `dateFormat` as @DuncanC described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate()`. I'm not familiar with that method, but it sounds like it expects a pre-defined date string template, and your format string must not match any known templates. If you change your line

```
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("w yyyy")
```

to

```
formatter.dateFormat = "w yyyy"
```

It works as expected.

### Edit:

It seems you should use:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "w Y"
```

`y` and `yyyy` will not give the correct results with certain dates.

Comment: You are using the wrong format, and believe it won't work as expected as it is. For `weekOfYear` you should use `Y` instead of `yyyy`

Comment: I'm just using the same formatString as the OP. Why would you need to use `Y` instead of `yyyy` when combined with `w` for week-of-year?

Comment: The year for weakOfYear dare component it is not necessarily the same as the regular yyyy

Comment: Yeah, I looked it up and saw that in the description. I wonder what that means more specifically? Why would the year be different for year/week-of-year than for year/month/day and other date expressions?

Comment: Try using y and Y but pass the last day of the year and you will see what I mean `let lastDayOFYear = DateComponents(calendar: .current, timeZone: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 31).date!` first week of 2019

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let weekOfYear = calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))
```

OR

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let weekOfYear = calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date())
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware of how to get the numbers and formatting them, it's about why the formatting string is special. I've updated my question.

Comment: @AllenZeng This answer is also incorrect. The correct year date component for weekOfYear is `yearForWeekOfYear`